# Showing that the Riemann integral does not depend on sample point

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The Riemann integral of a Riemann integrable bounded function $f:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is defined to be the $\inf\{ U(f,P)| \text{where P is a partition of [a,b]}\}$ or alternatively the $\sup\{ L(f,P)| \text{where P is a partition of [a,b]}\}$.

Here $U(f,P)$ is the upper Riemann sum and $L(f,P)$ is the lower Riemann sum of $f$.

Now let $(P_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a family of partitions of $[a,b]$ such that $|P_n| \rightarrow 0$. Define $$S_n(f) = \sum_{k = 1}^{N_n}f(t_k^{(n)})(x^{(n)}_{k}-x^{(n)}_{k-1})$$where $t_k$ is an arbitrary sample point in $[x_{k-1}, x_k]$.

I am trying to show that $S_n\rightarrow \int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$. But I am not sure how to go about doing this. How should I approach this?

Comment: You mean $$\int_a^b f (x)dx $$.

Answer (score 1):

For any $P$, we have $L(f,P)\le S(f,P)\le U(f,P)$.

Comment: Don't forget that we need to show that the bounds $\sup_P\{L(f, P)\}$ and $\inf_P\{U(f, P)\}$ actually are obtained by any single sequence $(P_n)_n$ of partitions as long as $(d_n)_n\to 0$, where $d_n$ is the width of the widest interval in the partition $P_n$.